# Jackson deserialize Double

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, rest-assured

I have a problem with deserialization of the JSON using Jackson in my rest-assured tests. 
In my JSON I have a key "value" that can be an array of Strings or object like Boolean.

```
{
 "value": ["value1", "value2"]
}
```

or

```
{
"value": 2272204.2426
}
```

So I wrote custom deserializer for this field:

```
public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);
        if (node.isArray()) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (JsonNode elementNode : node) {
                list.add(oc.treeToValue(elementNode, String.class));
            }
            return list;
        } else {
            if(node.isDouble()) {
                return oc.treeToValue(node, Double.class);
            }
            else if(node.isBoolean()){
                return oc.treeToValue(node, Boolean.class);
            }
            else {
                return oc.treeToValue(node, String.class);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the end I've noticed that numeric value like 2272204.2426 is deserialized to 2272204.2 
I tried to desierialize it using Gson and it works well. Do you have any idea why using Jackson there is lack of decimal part? 
I've tried to debug the code and I've noticed that on this step JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp); the value is 2272204.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `ObjectMapper` from Jackson? You can add `DeserializationFeature` to it unlike `ObjectCodec`. Mapper is actually extending Codec, but with more features that you need in this case.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS);

JsonNode node = //node where the value is defined as Double

Double value = null;
try {
    value = mapper.treeToValue(node, Double.class);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(value);
```

Use the above logic in your `node.isDouble()` case

Comment: I mentioned that this value field can be array or object, that is why I used custom deserializer and I'm using this construction 
@JsonDeserialize(using =ValueDeserializer.class)
private Object value;

value is just a one of the many field in my target object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works ok. I noticed in the different case that when I was using JsonPath to retrieve the objects from specific node there are decimal parts missing. According to issues list from the rest-assured project, JsonPath(string) will round decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to deserialize the doubles after adding **@AllArgsConstructor**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Data {
    private final Double first;
    private final Double second;
    private final Double third;
}
```